# c++: how to return a shared_ptr from function

Tags: c++, function, return, shared-ptr

when trying to return a shared_ptr from a function I get:
reference to local variable 'recipe' returned [-Werror=return-local-addr]

where did I go wrong ?

```
shared_ptr<Recipe>& Group::addRecipe(const string& groupName, unsigned int autherId, const string& recipeName){

    shared_ptr<Recipe> recipe(new Recipe(recipeName, autherId));

    recipes.push_back(recipe);
    return recipe;
}
```

what is the right way to return a shared_ptr ?

Comment: Sounds like your function is probably returning `shared_ptr&` instead of `shared_ptr`. Just return by value instead.

Comment: Yes, show function declaration, please

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: Are you asking what `reference to local variable returned` means?  That's your error.  You can't return a reference to a local variable.

Comment: is the problem that the " & " at the start of the declaration?

Comment: @user3776836 it looks like you're not sure what a _C++ reference_ is.  Does that sound right?

Answer (score 8):

The function's signature isn't shown, but it sounds like it's probably returning `shared_ptr<Recipe>&`. Returning a reference to a temporary is a big no-no since the referenced object will be destroyed as soon as the function exits. Just return by value instead.

Comment: shared_ptr<Recipe>& Group::addRecipe(const string& groupName, unsigned int autherId, const string& recipeName){

that's the signature, i'm new at this, what do you mean by "by value"? how do I do that?

Comment: @user3776836 please edit the question to contain the additional information.

Comment: @user3776836 Remove the `&` after `shared_ptr<Recipe>`. The `&` returns a reference making the return value reference a non existing object. Without the `&` you return an actual `shared_ptr<Recipe>` value.

Comment: In this case, returning by value just means dropping the &. A full discussion would be long, but there should be several questions on that subject.