# Return shared_ptr and hand it over to SDL_GL_SwapWindow

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, sdl-2

As I need a pointer to SDL_Window in different classes I thought it would be a good idea to use a shared_ptr.

```
//happens in class A::foo()
//shared_Window_A is of type std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>

shared_Window_A = std::make_shared<SDL_Window>(SDL_CreateWindow(..), SDL_DestroyWindow); 
GLContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(shared_Window_A.get()) //no compiler-error here

//Hand-over function of class A 
std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window> GetWindow(){return shared_Window_A;);

//happens in class B::bar()
//shared_Window_B is of type std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>

shared_Window_B = A.GetWindow();
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(shared_Window_B.get()); 
//gives "undefined reference to SDL_GL_SwapWindow"
```

Both `SDL_GL_SwapWindow` and `SDL_GL_CreateContext` want `SDL_Window* window`.

While I am obviously still learning about shared_ptrs, I do not really get what goes wrong here. I also tried it with the more ugly `(&(*shared_Window_B))`.

Overall it seems to work to handover the pointer to the SDL functions with `.get()` as long as they are in the same class: `SDL_GL_CreateContext(shared_Window_A.get())` seems to work/ not raise compiler errors in `A::foo()`.

Right now I am stuck and would like keep shared_ptr instead of raw pointers as it seems to work for other people. So I assume I simply did something wrong in handing over the shared_ptr from class A to class B. But searching for [returning a shared pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440613/c-how-to-return-a-shared-ptr-from-function) turns out that my attempt does not look so wrong.

So how do I hand over a shared_ptr from one class to another in a way that it works with SDL2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just pass in a pointer to `std::make_shared`. If the framework creates the object then you have to avoid `std::make_shared`. Perhaps this would work for you:

```
// shared_Window_A is of type std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>

auto win = SDL_CreateWindow(..); // get the pointer from the framework

// now pass it in to the shared pointer to manage its lifetime:
shared_Window_A = std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>(win, SDL_DestroyWindow);
```

Or succinctly:

```
shared_Window_A = std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>(SDL_CreateWindow(..), SDL_DestroyWindow);
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer! Unfortunatly, by doing this I get a lot of compiler-errors & warnings starting with: `error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'SDL_Window'` (in aligned_buffer.h) and ending with an `invalid use of struct SDL_Window ` (in new_allocator.h) and `error: forward declaration of struct SDL_Window` (in SDL_video.h). Any idea why this happens? With raw pointers it just ran smoothly, so "my" SDL seems not to be broken (?)

Comment: @Schloemmel I am not sure why that is happening. I can't test with `SDL` right now but there is an article about it here: https://eb2.co/blog/2014/04/c--14-and-sdl2-managing-resources/ or you can ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks again! I'll have a look on this and then see where it leads me. Anyway, you solved my question on how to hand over that shared_ptr, so I marked it as an answer. If I find a fix for that SDL behaviour I'll just update my question and link to it.